# How to check in Java using JIntegra if COM object implements an interface?

Tags: java, casting

I'm working with JIntegra java com bridge.
I have an object of type Object which true coclass is unknown.
I need to check if that object can be casted to specific COM interface (which has a proxy class generated by JIntegra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `queryInterface()` on the proxy. It should throw an exception if the underlying COM object does not implement the proxy interface.

Answer (score 0):

If the proxy class implements a (generated) interface, can you check if the object is an instanceof that?

Comment: No I can't, the generated proxy classes don't follow java conventions.
In order to case an object from one interface to another, I need to do some thing like <br/>
ISomeInterface = new ISomeInterfaceProxy(someObject); <br/>
But this action fails on method invocation and not on creation.

Comment: What's even worse... if you use an interface "C" that extends interface A & B, you get even stranger behavior. The proxy for "C" will work with any object that implements only A xor B, and won't fail until you hit a method that's in the non-implemented interface. Grrr!